# How to randomly assign an index date using R

Tags: r

I would like to:

1. randomly assign an index date to people in the df_1 according to the distribution of the index date in the df_2;
2. the newly assigned index date should be earlier than the death date of people (the death date contains NA)

Currently I am using:
`df_1 <-df_1 %>% mutate(index_date=sample(df_2$index_date, size=n(), replace=TRUE))`

However, I do not know how to limit the index date before the death_date in df_1.

Comment: example data would be nice...

Comment: Hi Jiker, please see my answer below, if it solved your problem, upvote and accept it, that would be very helpful; if not feel free to comment on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your data-format, but `rowwise` should do the trick:

```r
df_1 <- df_1 %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(index_date = sample(df_2$index_date[df_2$index_date <= death_date], size=1)) %>% 
    ungroup()
```

Repex with `mtcars`:

```r
mtcars %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(mpg_rand = sample(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$mpg <= mpg], 1))
```